# mach_wait_until() Strange Behavior on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, timer, ios-simulator

I created a simple project to test out the functionality of `mach_wait_until()`.  This code gives me an accurate printout of how precise the 1 second delay is.  The console printout is virtually identical and extremely precise on both the iOS Simulator and on my iPad Air 2.  However, on my iPad there is a HUGE delay, where the same 1 second delay takes about 100 seconds!  And to add to the weirdness of it, the printout in the console says it only takes 1 second (with extremely low jitter and/or lag).

How can this be?  Is there some timing conversion that I need to do for a physical iOS device when using `mach_wait_until()`?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      playNoteTest()
    }

    var start = mach_absolute_time()
    var end = mach_absolute_time()

    func playNoteTest() {
      let when = mach_absolute_time() + 1000000000

      self.start = mach_absolute_time()
      mach_wait_until(when)
      self.end = mach_absolute_time()
      let timeDelta = (self.end - self.start)
      let newTimeDelta = Double(timeDelta) / 1000000000.0
      print("Delta Time = \(newTimeDelta)")

      playNoteTest()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mach_absolute_time` units are CPU dependent.  You need to multiply by a device-specific constant in order to get real-world units.  It is discussed in this [Tech Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html) from Apple.

Here is some playground code that demonstrates the idea:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class TimeBase {
    static let NANOS_PER_USEC: UInt64 = 1000
    static let NANOS_PER_MILLISEC: UInt64 = 1000 * NANOS_PER_USEC
    static let NANOS_PER_SEC: UInt64 = 1000 * NANOS_PER_MILLISEC

    static var timebaseInfo: mach_timebase_info! = {
        var tb = mach_timebase_info(numer: 0, denom: 0)
        let status = mach_timebase_info(&tb)
        if status == KERN_SUCCESS {
            return tb
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }()

    static func toNanos(abs:UInt64) -> UInt64 {
        return (abs * UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer)) / UInt64(timebaseInfo.denom)      
    }

    static func toAbs(nanos:UInt64) -> UInt64 {
        return (nanos * UInt64(timebaseInfo.denom)) / UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer)
    }

}

let duration = TimeBase.toAbs(nanos: 10 * TimeBase.NANOS_PER_SEC)

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

    print("Start")
    let start = mach_absolute_time()
    mach_wait_until(start+duration)
    let stop = mach_absolute_time()

    let elapsed = stop-start
    let elapsedNanos = TimeBase.toNanos(abs: elapsed)
    let elapsedSecs = elapsedNanos/TimeBase.NANOS_PER_SEC
    print("Elapsed nanoseconds = \(elapsedNanos)")
    print("Elapsed seconds = \(elapsedSecs)")

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have one more associated question...  My above code gives very accurate timing repetition, however, it basically freezes me out of all functionality of my app.  The CPU doesn't go up on the diagnostics in Simulator.  Does a method like `mach_wait_until()` just require to be put on a separate thread to solve that problem?  If so, could you add example code in your answer to address this aspect?  or do you think I should create a new question for this?

Comment: Yes, `mach_wait_until` blocks the current thread.  Running it on the main thread/queue is a Bad Idea™

Comment: Great!  I guess it’s time for me to learn how to multithread then...  if there’s an easy way you can add that to your example, I would be grateful

Comment: See the update for an example of dispatching work onto a background queue

Comment: Thank you for adding the `DispatchQueue` code fore clarity.  Unfortunately, this answer is not solving my problem yet...  The code works just as well as my simpler, "incorrect" code above on Simulator.  With my above code, the timing happened much too slow on my physical iPad.  Now that I've replaced it with your code with it's "device specific constant" as specified by Apple, the timing is going WAY too fast...  In my code, it is delaying/looping on at 15-60ms!!  Instead of the intended 1 second (which I prescribed in "duration", which you have listed at 10 (seconds)).

Comment: More bizarrely... When I print the "duration" var to console, when I use the iPad it says "duration = 0" no matter what the value is in the code!?  When done in Simulator it comes back correctly as 1 or 10 secs, etc.  Since your code example was written for playground, I'm guessing there's some other prerequisite to get this to work on an iPad you left out that I don't know?  Or implemented your code in an incorrect way?

Comment: A friend on FB pointed out a problem in your code.  I changed it and it works correctly now!  Thanks for helping me get 99% of the way there paulw1!